# why message queue consumer never exiting when --max-messages specified?

Tags: magento2, cron, rabbit-mq, message-queue

I'm using Magento 2.3.4 with RabbitMQ configured in the `env.php` to process my message queues, I start consumer using:

```
bin/magento queue:consumers:start ConsumerName --max-messages 1
```

But the consumer keeps listening forever, never exits.

It seems to be a [native issue in Magento](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/17951), how could I solve it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had to force the setting to be 0 by adding the below to `env.php`:

```
'queue' => [
    'consumers_wait_for_messages' => 0
],
```

If you look at this file: `vendor/magento/framework-message-queue/CallbackInvoker.php`

You will see that Magento 2 actually makes the default for this setting 1 (contrary to the documentation)

```
/**
 * Checks if consumers should wait for message from the queue
 *
 * @return bool
 */
private function isWaitingNextMessage(): bool
{
    return $this->deploymentConfig->get('queue/consumers_wait_for_messages', 1) === 1;
}
```

After doing that, my other cron processes started running again and I no longer saw the parent cron job as "stuck"

Full article [here](https://www.cadence-labs.com/2020/03/magento-2-stuck-or-long-running-cron-after-upgrade-to-2-3-x/).

Reference [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/17951#issuecomment-605527835).