# Should cron jobs get terminated or run forever?

Tags: magento2, cron

When I do `ps aux | grep queue` I get the following list of processes that were started via cronjobs:

```
webmast+ 2309182  0.0  0.0 366472  4592 ?        S    Sep29   3:29 /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/emark/shop/bin/magento queue:consumers:start product_action_attribute.update --single-thread --max-messages=10000
webmast+ 2309184  0.0  0.0 366472  3104 ?        S    Sep29   3:28 /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/emark/shop/bin/magento queue:consumers:start product_action_attribute.website.update --single-thread --max-messages=10000
webmast+ 2309186  0.0  0.0 366472  3088 ?        S    Sep29   3:31 /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/emark/shop/bin/magento queue:consumers:start exportProcessor --single-thread --max-messages=10000
webmast+ 2309188  0.0  0.0 366472  3028 ?        S    Sep29   3:29 /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/emark/shop/bin/magento queue:consumers:start inventory.source.items.cleanup --single-thread --max-messages=10000
webmast+ 2309190  0.0  0.0 366604  2204 ?        S    Sep29   3:28 /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/emark/shop/bin/magento queue:consumers:start inventory.mass.update --single-thread --max-messages=10000
webmast+ 2309192  0.0  0.0 366476  2984 ?        S    Sep29   3:28 /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/emark/shop/bin/magento queue:consumers:start inventory.reservations.cleanup --single-thread --max-messages=10000
webmast+ 2309194  0.0  0.0 366476  3044 ?        S    Sep29   3:27 /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/emark/shop/bin/magento queue:consumers:start inventory.reservations.update --single-thread --max-messages=10000
webmast+ 2309196  0.0  0.0 366472  3092 ?        S    Sep29   3:28 /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/emark/shop/bin/magento queue:consumers:start codegeneratorProcessor --single-thread --max-messages=10000
```

They were started at 29th of September. Now it is the 2nd of October, so they run for a couple of days already. It this how it should be or should those processes get terminated already? Does that indicate something goes wrong?

**Update:** The actual problem seems to be what is described [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/312699/12971). It is not the cronjob itself, rather it is about Magento's message queue processing and the env.php setting 
[consumers_wait_for_messages](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/prod/config-reference-envphp.html#consumers_wait_for_messages).

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is something wrong in your cron. Please check your cron functionality whether it process millions of data or what. If yes then also it should not run 2 days.

Kill the cron process and debug your cron functionality and add exception handler in your cron so you can have error if something is wrong in your cron process.

Comment: I think it could be a problem with not ending concumer processes, because of a setting in env.php. Found [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/312700/12971) and will try it...

Comment: then all cron jobs should be affected.....

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are not config for Cron jobs and current is using default config. To check Cron schedule tasks. Go to admin > stores > configuration > system > Cron (Scheduled) Task. Hope it help.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But it doesn't help me. I'd like to know whether it is normal that those processes run that long. I thought they terminate quickly and gets created each time the cron job gets triggered.